# Database fragmentation and heap SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index, fragmentation, heap

We have critical performance issues with our production database (its around 300 gb size)
We have run the following script for a few huge tables :

```
DECLARE @db_id SMALLINT;
DECLARE @object_id INT;

SET @db_id = DB_ID(N'master');
SET @object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'master.dbo.tTable');

IF @db_id IS NULL
BEGIN;
    PRINT N'Invalid database';
END;
ELSE IF @object_id IS NULL
BEGIN;
    PRINT N'Invalid object';
END;
ELSE
BEGIN;
    SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(@db_id, @object_id, NULL, NULL , 'LIMITED');
END;
GO
```

and get the following relults :

**First table:**

`index_type_desc` : HEAP

`alloc_unit_type_desc` : IN_ROW_DATA

`index_depth`: 1

`index_level`: 0

`avg_fragmentation_in_percent` : 81.1555698682339

`fragment_count` : 163818

`avg_fragment_size_in_pages` : 8.4652052887961

`page_count` : 1386753

**Second table :**

`index_type_desc` : HEAP

`alloc_unit_type_desc` : IN_ROW_DATA

`index_depth`: 1

`index_level`: 0

`avg_fragmentation_in_percent`: 82.2484358706986

`fragment_count` : 76826

`avg_fragment_size_in_pages`: 6.87469085986515

`page_count` : 528155

For non-clustered indexes the `avg_framgentation_values` value is too low.
Are we have a problem with clustered index ? And what can we do with it to improve our performance ?

Comment: You can't have a problem with clustered indexes because these tables don't have clustered indexes. Was that an intentional choice? Why?

Comment: We have a lot of non-clustered indexes for our queries includes non-clustered index for one Id field. It seems we haven't got a clustered indexes, also, in our queries we have the query whose execution plan contains  `RID Lookup (HEAP) 94%`

Comment: What is advantage of using clustered indexes ?

Comment: You have a RID lookup because an index is used to locate rows, but it isn't *covering* - e.g. you have columns you want to output (or are used for additional filter or join criteria, though most commonly this is from SELECT *) that can't be found in the index, so need to be retrieved from the heap.

Comment: thanks, but is heap fragmentation can affects on performance ?

Comment: Clustered > heap for a variety of reasons, but heaps are preferred in a few specialty uses. See [Kimberly Tripp's post, which shows that most operations are faster with a supporting clustered index](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/), and [this post](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2009/02/27/reasons-why-you-may-not-want-to-use-a-heap/) which has some interesting commentary. Long story short: yes, heaps (especially fragmented ones) can affect performance (but to what extent, there is no simple answer).

Comment: FYI Also under the right circumstances heaps can cause a space leak. http://sqlstudies.com/2014/08/25/the-amazing-never-shrinking-heap/

Comment: Watch this video http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/05/video-heaps/

Comment: Can you explain more about your performance issue? Is it application related? Can you trace the issue to a specific query? Has performance suddenly degraded? Or has this been getting worse over time?

Comment: We have a lot of timeout errors, many services and site connect to database and lock some data, i need investigate this issue deeper, can you give me an advice how can i find all bottlenecks in sql server work ? Also, that is known issues, but new issue brings us decline of performance to critical low level, i think it starts before we made huge edit and deletion of data in db.